# Store fields in the database and read the same in logging

Tags: php, database, wordpress

after connecting wordpress with another server, I get a special ID from that other server, but it is related to the ID from the wordpress user, how can I save this second ID to the base, and submit it to the user who after the login ?

```
    $user_id = $arr['id'];

if($user_id){
     $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;


     /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
     server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
     $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "localm");

     // Check connection
     if($link === false){
         die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
     }
      //
     // Attempt insert query execution
     $sql = 'INSERT INTO wp_users (user_id) VALUES ("'.$user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'].'");';
     if(mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
         echo "Records inserted successfully.";
     } else{
         echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
     }
     // Close connection
     mysqli_close($link);
```

I am currently using $ _SESSION and this id is saved while in that browser, but when the time it is signed it is gone. That is why I have to keep it in the base .. Which resets would be the easiest for this case? Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

This will work with you if I understood the question ..
You will save the another ID to the add_user_meta, Then call it using the current Wordpress user ID and get_user_meta

```html
function save_ID( $user )
{
   //get current user details
   if( !$user ) { $user = wp_get_current_user(); }
   
   //check if session registered
   if( !isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ){ return; }

   //store the 2nd ID to user_meta
   $user_id = $user->ID;
   $another_id = esc_html( esc_js( $_SESSION['user_id'] ) );
   add_user_meta( $user_id, 'user_2nd_id', $another_id);
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'save_ID');
```

I hope I helped you.
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks firstly at the announcement, that I need to keep this my id and to call with the id of the wp user when he logins .. where can I include this code?